# Javascript library function not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting problem while calling a function in included javascript library function daypilotMonth. It says undefined is not a function. I checked daypilot-all.min.js is loading correctly. I really can't figure out which other way is to do it. This is I am doing in ASP.NET mvc page.

Any help will be great. Thanks

```
<script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/daypilot-all.min.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        dp = $("#dpm").daypilotMonth({
            backendUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Schedule/Backend")',
            eventMoveHandling: "CallBack",
            eventResizeHandling: "CallBack",
            timeRangeSelectedHandling: "JavaScript",
            onTimeRangeSelected: function(start, end) {
                dp.timeRangeSelectedCallBack(start, end, {
                    name: prompt('New Event Name:', 'New Event')
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<p>
    <div style="margin:20%" id="dpm"></div>
</p>
} 
@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the script not recognize

```
 backendUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Schedule/Backend")'
```

try change to

```
   backendUrl: @Url.Content("~/Schedule/Backend")
```

Answer (score -1):

check you have correct syntax in javascript code. It might be some typo. For me it I made a typo. it should be

```
$("#ddlCustomer").val()
```

instead of

```
$(#ddlCustomer)
```